# Float error while attempting to use the bisect optimizer within scipy

Tags: python, optimization, scipy

I’m having trouble using the bisect optimizer within scipy. Here are the relevant portions of my code:

How I’m importing things

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.optimize as sp
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

Break in code, section causing errors below

```
#All variables are previously defined except for h
def BeamHeight(h):
    x = 1000e3*M[i]*h/(fw*h^3-(fw-wt)(h-2*ft)^3) - Max_stress_steel
    return x
for i in range(0,50):
    h = np.zeros((50))  
    h[i] = sp.bisect(BeamHeight, hb, 5,xtol = 0.001)
```

Causing this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ShearMoment.py", line 63, in <module>
    h[i] = sp.bisect(BeamHeight, hb, 5,xtol = 0.001)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/optimize/zeros.py", line 248, in bisect
    r = _zeros._bisect(f,a,b,xtol,rtol,maxiter,args,full_output,disp)
  File "ShearMoment.py", line 58, in BeamHeight
    x = 1000e3*M[i]*h/(fw*h^3-(fw-wt)(h-2*ft)^3) - Max_stress_steel
TypeError: 'float' object is not callable
```

I understand that scipy.optimize expects a function as one of its arguments. Am I doing this incorrectly?

Answer (score 3):

In Python, concatenation is not implicitly multiplication, and `^` is not exponentiation. Multiplication must be made explicit with `*`, and exponentiation must be written as `**`. This part of `BeamHeight`:

```
fw*h^3-(fw-wt)(h-2*ft)^3
```

must be written as

```
fw*h**3-(fw-wt)*(h-2*ft)**3
```